# Why don't my App Bar icons show up when I build?

Tags: android

I am working on an App Bar for navigation in my Android app.  I am using an xml menu file.  In the design view, the icons will show up, like in the first image:

[Design view of Android Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NkD34.png)

But when I build and launch the app in the emulator, the appBar shows up with out the icon, like this:

[Android emulator without the icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DtVnc.png)

I have also tested this on a physical device, and I get the exact same problem.

Here is my menu.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <!-- Top bar navigation menu-->

    <!-- "Show EPA scale", should appear as action button if possible -->
    <item
        android:id="@+id/showEpaScale"

        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_wb_sunny_black_24dp"
        android:title="@string/epaScaleUri"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

</menu>
```

And here is my MainActivity:

```
package com.weebly.stevelosk.uv_buddy;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.annotation.ArrayRes;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Calendar;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView resultTextView;
    private TextView UV_indexDescriptionTextView;
    private EditText enterZipCodeEditText;
    private Button getUV_withZipCodeButton;
    private Button getUV_withLocationButton;
    private Toolbar mActionBar;

    private Integer[] uviArray;

    private String TAG = "Main Activity";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mActionBar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(mActionBar);
...
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.showEpaScale:
                // User chose the "Settings" item, show the app settings UI...
                // Do stuff
                return true;

            default:
                return true;
        }
    }
```

Am I missing something?  I have followed along with the instructions in the android developer training (Setting Up the App Bar) and (Adding and Handling Actions).  I have also tried searching several variations of this question on stackoverflow, but none of the results I am finding really match my problem.  I tried using a "known good icon" instead, which also shows up in the design view  but not when I compile and run in the emulator.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: `mActionBar.inflateMenu(R.menu.mymenuname)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to override `onCreateMenuInflater`:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.game_menu, menu);
    return true;
}
```